# I have a gas problem Do i come under Madhur rulingr?

Tags: salat, wudu

So i have a problem in which i have a continous gas problem.Because of this its very difficult to pray. Lately i came to know about the madhur ruling where a person is excused for a problem he is suffering so he can take wudhu and if he releases anything his wudhu wont break. But recently i am wondering whether i come under this madhur ruling ?

There is always a ton of gas in my stomach. I dont release it all in one go but in small amounts every few minutes. Usually i dont release it when i am not in wudhu , atleast i dont notice it being released. But when i take wudhu I get nervous and then i feel gas in my stomach and start praying i cant help but feel that i released gas especially when i go down in ruku and sujood.I have another problem whereby it is really difficult to hold in the gas because my gaspipe muscles are 'loose' - meaning that my voluntary muscles have lost much of their ability to constrict. The result is the unevitable release of a small amount of gas every once in a while. It is a mental-physical problem

I have to try and take wudhu several times sometimes as less as 3 to as much as 10 times .This causes me great tension and grief and anger. Because of this tension i have los weight too and become thin. Whats more i am not an adult and this is a great burden. Sometimes i feel like i may go insane and die after taking wudhu around 10 times. I am physically, mentally and spiritually exhausted after all this.

Now the question is do i come under the madhur ruling ? Am i a madhur ?

Certainly Allah (may he be glorified) has said :'Do not overburden yourselves lest you perish'

Jazallahu Khair

Comment: https://www.ilmgate.org/rules-related-to-an-excused-person-madhur/

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/8910/does-continually-passing-wind-invalidate-wudoo

Comment: Yes you come under madhur ruling

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly Shaytan that wants to make Salah as hard as possible for you. 10 times wudhu is way too much for just gas.
Doubt doens't break wudhu. What breaks wudhu is smell and sound. If you never smell and never hear your farts then just pray and don't think about doing wudhu over and over again.